# Galaxy tab can't connect to ADB

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, galaxy-tab

I working in Ubuntu. I need to connect Samsung Galaxy Tab to ADB on this OS. I doing all in this manual: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html but galaxy tab still don't connect to ADB. When I execute "./adb devices", I get one device with name like this: "?????????". What could be the problem and how to solve it?

P.S. Ubuntu and ADB work correct. I can connect HTC Wildfire to ADB, but Samsung galaxy tab still can't...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've done this:

Open the following file as a root:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

Then, add the following line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Save file and exit. Now check if the device is shown.

EDIT: You may need to restart your pc and device. I not sure about that, but just to be on the safe side...